# Json serialization format

Tags: http, uuid

I'm fairly new to Json. I can't understand the resource from this URL: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Neutron/LBaaS/API_1.0#Remove_a_VIP

My `vip_id` field has been named with numbers such as `1`, `2`, `3`, etc, so in the example, when they send the request `DELETE /v1.0/vips/02b1fef7-16f5-4917-bf19-c40a9af805ed`, why is the `vip_id` field not numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc)? In other words, why is the request not in in the format of `DELETE /v1.0/vips/1`? What is `02b1fef7-16f5-4917-bf19-c40a9af805ed`?

Answer (score 0):

`02b1fef7-16f5-4917-bf19-c40a9af805ed` is a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). The description says, that the URL pattern is

```
/v1.0/vips/{vip_id}
```

where `vip_id` seems to be an UUID. It identifies a resource to delete.

If you read the example how a VIP is created using `POST`, it looks like such a resource get's an id that is a UUID. So I doubt that you can create a VIP with an ID of `1` or  `2`.

**Edit**

Of course this depends on the concrete system, but the important thing to understand is the format of an URI. Each VIP is identified by an ID. The path of the URI for a VIP has the format

```
/v1.0/vips/{vip_id}
```

This format has three parts.

- `/v1.0`: The version of the system
- `/vips`: The collection of *all* VIPs
- `/{vip_id}`: A placeholder for the ID of a concrete VIP.

If the system allows UUIDs for the `vip_id`, an URI path like

```
/v1.0/vips/02b1fef7-16f5-4917-bf19-c40a9af805ed
```

can identify a VIP. It looks like a simple integer can be used, too. Then an URI path like

```
/v1.0/vips/1
```

identifies a VIP, too.

In a RESTful system, you use HTTP verbs like `GET` or `DELETE` to interact with resources. If you want to get the details of a concrete VIP, you issue a `GET` request for its URI. If you want to delete it (perhaps together with any children), you issue a `DELETE` request to its URI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lutz. Please take a look at http://www.openflowhub.org/display/floodlightcontroller/Load+Balancer. I have tried this example and it works. As you can see the "id" field of the vips are "1" and "2".  The purpose of my question is just to understand the format of the request allowing me to remove an vip.

Comment: I had the exact same thought as you for the DELETE restful request. I tried /v1.0/vips/1 using a DELETE request but it doesn't work. The online manual resource is very clear but for some reason my request just doesn't work; and I have no idea why.

Comment: I don't receive any response from my Floodlight server. No error message. I managed to solve my problem with a work around. All I know is the vip still exists. Nonetheless, thank you for the help.